# State object once and retrieve multiple attributes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Here is a snippet from a Sinatra app where users will be submitting urls. I must ensure that `http://` is prepended to the url in order to route outside my application. How can I state `site` once and access it's attributes? (Line 3)

```
  p.params= "www.ruby-lang.org/en/"
  site = URI(p.params[:url])
  site = "http://" + site.host + site.path + site.query
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to ensure the url begins with `http://`, why not use a regex?

```
p.params = "www.ruby-lang.org/en/"
site = p.params.gsub(/^(­?!http:\/\­/)/, "http­://")
# site = http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/
```

`^(­?!http:\/\­/)` matches only when the beginning of the string is *not* followed by `http://`

Comment: Instead of throwing the user an error for not including 'http://', I wanted to side-step the issue completely by pulling the host, path, and query (if present) from the string and prepending it automatically.

Comment: This method doesn't throw an error. It simply prepends `http://` only if needed. Otherwise, it sets `site` to the original URL.